# How to update toValue/fromValue of CABasicAnimation to be smoother when changed?

Tags: ios, swift3, cabasicanimation

I've 2 animations applied to CAShapeLayer(let's name it `pulseLayer`), with this code :

```
let scaledAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
scaledAnimation.duration       = 0.75
scaledAnimation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
scaledAnimation.autoreverses   = true
scaledAnimation.fromValue      = 4
scaledAnimation.toValue        = 4
scaledAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

let heartBeatAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
heartBeatAnimation.duration       = 0.75
heartBeatAnimation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
heartBeatAnimation.autoreverses   = true
heartBeatAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
heartBeatAnimation.toValue        = 1.2
heartBeatAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

pulseLayer.add(heartBeatAnimation, forKey: "heartBeatAnimation")
```

at some point while `heartBeatAnimation` is on I need to remove heart beat animation and add the scaled animation with this code :

```
pulseLayer.add(self.scaledAnimation, forKey: "scaledAnimation")
pulseLayer.opacity = 0.55
pulseLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "heartBeatAnimation")
```

but I didn't get any smooth transition between this two animation, even with `UIView.animate()`

so I tried to stay with only one animation `heartBeatAnimation` and change its `toValue` `fromValue` to the same value to get as `scaledAnimation` with this code :

```
heartBeatAnimation.toValue = 4
heartBeatAnimation.fromValue = 4
```

nothing happened while the animation is beating after the animation gone and the user does some gesture to start the animation I got the scaled steady animation...!

so any ideas how to update these values to make the scaled animation smoother!

Comment: i think you need to set heartBeatAnimation.toValue = 4, heartBeatAnimation.fromValue = 0, for smooth transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see. Complete animation and switching between both is depends upon 
`duration, count, fromValue and toValue` properties of CABasicAnimation with `UIView.animate` closure

```
@IBOutlet var vwAnimation: UIView!
    let initialScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    let animatingScale: CGFloat = 2.0
    let finalScale: CGFloat = 3.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addAnimation()
    }


    func addAnimation(){

        heartBeatAnimation()
        self.perform(#selector(self.switchAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)
    }

    @objc func switchAnimation(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.vwAnimation.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "heartBeatAnimation")
            self.scaledAnimation()
            self.vwAnimation.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (isCompleted) in

        }
    }


    func scaledAnimation() -> Void {

        let scaledAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        scaledAnimation.duration       = 0.5
        scaledAnimation.repeatCount    = 0.5
        scaledAnimation.autoreverses   = true
        scaledAnimation.fromValue      = initialScale
        scaledAnimation.toValue        = finalScale
        scaledAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
        vwAnimation.layer.add(scaledAnimation, forKey: "scaledAnimation")

        self.perform(#selector(self.adjustScale), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
    }

    @objc func adjustScale(){
        self.vwAnimation.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "scaledAnimation")
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: finalScale, y: finalScale)
        vwAnimation.transform = scaleTransform
    }


    func heartBeatAnimation() -> Void {

        let heartBeatAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        heartBeatAnimation.duration       = 0.5
        heartBeatAnimation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
        heartBeatAnimation.autoreverses   = true
        heartBeatAnimation.fromValue      = initialScale
        heartBeatAnimation.toValue        = animatingScale
        heartBeatAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
        vwAnimation.layer.add(heartBeatAnimation, forKey: "heartBeatAnimation")

    }
```

Here is result of above code and let me know if want changes in this result:

[image]

Comment: I want to scale and stay scaled not just with a blink !

Comment: I meant I want to stay scaled.

Comment: Yaa, It is scaled `3x (scaleOfView  = 3.0)` at end of animation, You can see here

Comment: Nice but you could also use CATransaction completion blocks instead of delays. Just letting you know.

Comment: @agibson007 Good advice. Please update this answer according to your advice.

Comment: @Krunal check it out

Answer (score 0):

Without using delays and such and using CATransaction and CASpringAnimations.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var shapeLayer : CAShapeLayer!
    var button : UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //add a shapelayer
        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/4, height: self.view.bounds.width/4)
        shapeLayer.position = self.view.center
        shapeLayer.path = drawStarPath(frame: shapeLayer.bounds).cgPath
        let color = UIColor(red: 0.989, green: 1.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)


        //button for action
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width - 20, height: 50))
        button.center = self.view.center
        button.center.y = self.view.bounds.height - 70
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Animate", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)

        self.view.addSubview(button)

  }

  func pressed(sender:UIButton) {

        if button.titleLabel?.text == "Reset Layer"{
            reset()
            return
        }


        //perform Animation
        button.isEnabled = false
        button.setTitle("Animating...", for: .normal)

        let heartBeatAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        heartBeatAnimation.duration       = 0.5
        heartBeatAnimation.repeatCount    = 2
        heartBeatAnimation.autoreverses   = true
        heartBeatAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
        heartBeatAnimation.toValue        = 2.0
        heartBeatAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { 
            //call when finished
            [weak self] in
            if let vc = self{
                vc.scaleUpToComplete()
            }

        }
        shapeLayer.add(heartBeatAnimation, forKey: "beatAnimation")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

    func scaleUpToComplete(){

        let scaledAnimation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        scaledAnimation.duration       = 0.7
        scaledAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
        scaledAnimation.toValue        = 2.0
        scaledAnimation.damping = 8.0
        scaledAnimation.initialVelocity = 9
        scaledAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { 
            //set transform
            [weak self] in
            if let vc = self{
                let scaleTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 2.0, 2.0, 1)
                vc.shapeLayer.transform = scaleTransform
                vc.shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()

                //button title and enabled
                vc.button.isEnabled = true
                vc.button.setTitle("Reset Layer", for: .normal)

            }
        }
        shapeLayer.add(scaledAnimation, forKey: "scaleUp")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }


    func reset(){
        let scaledAnimation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
        scaledAnimation.duration       = 0.7
        scaledAnimation.fromValue      = 2.0
        scaledAnimation.toValue        = 1.0
        scaledAnimation.damping = 8.0
        scaledAnimation.initialVelocity = 9
        scaledAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            //set transform
            [weak self] in
            if let vc = self{
                let scaleTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1.0, 1.0, 1)
                vc.shapeLayer.transform = scaleTransform
                vc.shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
                vc.button.setTitle("Animate", for: .normal)
            }
        }
        shapeLayer.add(scaledAnimation, forKey: "scaleDown")
        CATransaction.commit()

    }

    func drawStarPath(frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 140)) ->UIBezierPath{
        //// Star Drawing
        let starPath = UIBezierPath()
        starPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.50000 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.21071 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.60202 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.35958 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.77513 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.41061 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.66508 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.55364 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.67004 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.73404 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.50000 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.67357 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.32996 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.73404 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.33492 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.55364 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.22487 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.41061 * frame.height))
        starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 0.39798 * frame.width, y: frame.minY + 0.35958 * frame.height))
        return starPath
    }
}
```